# What does line.split(",")[1] mean [Java]?

Tags: java, string, double, value-of

I came across code where i had encountered with `Double.valueOf(line.split(",")[1])`
I am familiar with `Double.valueOf()` and my problem is to understand what does `[1]` mean in the sentence. Searched docs didn't find anything.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                double crtValue = Double.valueOf(line.split(",")[1]);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: `line#split` returns an array, `[1]` acceses the second element of the returned array.

Comment: @KevinEsche uhm, no, the 2nd element; unless you mean element at index 0 to be the 0th element

Comment: @fge you´re right, fixed it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that your `line` is a String of numbers separated by commas.
eg: `"12.34,45.0,67.1"`

The `line.split(",")` returns an array of Strings.
eg: `{"12.34","45.0","67.1"}`

`line.split(",")[1]` returns the **2nd**(because indexes begin at 0) item of the array.
eg: `45.0`

Answer (score 3):

It means `line` is a string beginning with `a,b` where `b` is in fact a number.

`crtValue` is the `double` value of `b`.

Answer (score 3):

Java [`public String[] split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

It

> **Returns:** the array of **strings** computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression

So the `[1]` gets the 2nd item of the array found in `String[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code tries to get the second `double` value from `reader.readLine()`.

---

1. `String numbers = "1.21,2.13,3.56,4.0,5";`
2. `String[] array = numbers.split(",");` split the input line by commma
3. `String second = array[1];` get the second element from the array. Java array numeration starts from `0` index.
4. `double crtValue = Double.valueOf(second);` convert `String` to `double`

---

Don't forget about `NumberFormatException` that may be thrown if the string does not contain a parsable `double`.